# Create word embeddings without keeping fastText Vector file in the repository

Tags: nlp, word-embeddings

I am trying to embed a sentence with the help of [Infersent](https://github.com/facebookresearch/InferSent), and Infersent uses [fastText](https://dl.fbaipublicfiles.com/fasttext/vectors-english/crawl-300d-2M-subword.zip) vectors for word embedding. The fastText vector file is close to 5 GiB.

When we keep the fastText vector file along with the code repository it makes the repository size huge, and makes the code difficult to share/deploy (even creating a docker container).

Is there any method to avoid keeping the vector file along with the repository, but reuse it for embedding new sentences?